# SegWit-incapable miners won't include SegWit tx's but accept them as valid?

Tags: segregated-witness

Why SegWit-incapable miners won't include SegWit tx's in their blocks but will accept as valid someone else's block with SegWit tx's in it?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42634/can-unupgraded-nodes-that-accept-zero-confirmation-be-fooled-after-segwit/42642

Comment: @G.Maxwell "Among old nodes, the transaction is not propagated because it is non-standard", but how these tx's are accepted as valid by old nodes when inside a mined block?

Comment: If a pre-segwit miner would include a segwit tx in a block (which they won't accidentally do, due to nonstandardness), that block will be invalid to segwit miners. The latter would just ignore that block and build a chain that does not include it.

Comment: @PieterWuille, this I understand, but what about the other way around? Do pre-segwit miners receive blocks by segwit miners with segwit tx's in them and accept them as valid? Being "nonstandard" and "valid" are different things?

Comment: Nonstandard means "won't relay or include in a block" (which is a local policy). Invalid means "would be invalid in a block" (which is a network wide rule). Segwit has been constructed such that a block with witness transactions will be valid to pre-segwit nodes.

Comment: @PieterWuille , perfectly clear now. Thank you for the attention and patience